# this sql query not returning all data from joined table

Tags: sql

IN this sql we are looking for subst_instructions from the formulary table. we are getting only 1 or 2 of these, even though there should be others with same med in the first table:

```
select * from (SELECT  ID_KEY, [BATCH] AS column1, [IMPORTDATE], [DATEBILLED], [RX], [DATEDISPENSED], [DAYSUPPLY], [PAYTYPE], [NPI],
 [PHYSICIAN], [COST], [QUANTITY], [MEDICATION], A.[NDC], [PATIENTNAME], [ROUTEOFADMIN], [INVOICECAT], [COPAY], [BRAND], [TIER], [SKILLLEVEL], 
 [STAT] STATUS, [LASTTASKDATE],SEQNO,B.[SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS], row_number() over(partition by ID_KEY order by ID_KEY) rn FROM [PBM].[T_CHARGES] A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [OGEN].[NDC_M_FORMULARY] B ON A.[NDC] = B.[NDC]  Where [STAT] not in (3, 4) AND [TIER] <> 'T1'  )a where rn = 1
```

---

Here is the query that ended up working:

```
select * from (SELECT ID_KEY, [BATCH] AS column1, [IMPORTDATE], [DATEBILLED], [RX], />    [DATEDISPENSED], [DAYSUPPLY], [PAYTYPE], [NPI],
 [PHYSICIAN], [COST], [QUANTITY], [MEDICATION], A.[NDC], [PATIENTNAME], [ROUTEOFADMIN], <br>  [INVOICECAT], [COPAY], [BRAND], [TIER], [SKILLLEVEL], <br>  
 [STAT] STATUS, [LASTTASKDATE],SEQNO,B.[SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS],<br>   row_number() over(partition by ID_KEY order by ID_KEY) rn FROM [PBM].[T_CHARGES] A<br>  
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [OGEN].[NDC_M_FORMULARY] B ON A.[NDC] = B.[NDC]  Where [STAT] not in <br>  (3, 4) AND [TIER] <> 'T1'  )a where SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS is not null -- rn = 1
```

Comment: Great, so what do you want us to do about it?

Comment: I think the issue is, i am joining to a keyed table, on NDC number which is not unique.

Comment: IOW, this is simple join really. we have our main table and we need to get substr_instructions. what is abetter way to code this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes Nulls can hide data you want.

e.g.

```
  CREATE TABLE #STAT (
   ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
   STAT INT NULL )

   INSERT INTO #STAT (STAT)
   SELECT 3 UNION ALL
   SELECT NULL UNION ALL
   SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
   SELECT 5 

   SELECT * FROM #STAT

   SELECT * FROM #STAT WHERE [STAT] NOT IN (3,4)
```

To get around this, use COALESCE

```
SELECT * FROM #STAT WHERE COALESCE([STAT],0) NOT IN (3,4)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `where rn = 1` is going to be limiting, if you run the query without that, do the results look more like you expect?

Comment: without that, it gives duplicates. WHich is why i went that route. I tried 2 and 3 there, it returned more but not all of the substr_instructions

Answer (score 0):

This is your query with slightly better formatting:

```
select *
from (SELECT ID_KEY, [BATCH] AS column1, [IMPORTDATE], [DATEBILLED], [RX], [DATEDISPENSED],
               [DAYSUPPLY], [PAYTYPE], [NPI], [PHYSICIAN], [COST], [QUANTITY], [MEDICATION],
               A.[NDC], [PATIENTNAME], [ROUTEOFADMIN], [INVOICECAT], [COPAY], [BRAND], [TIER],
               [SKILLLEVEL], [STAT] STATUS, [LASTTASKDATE], SEQNO, B.[SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS],
              row_number() over(partition by ID_KEY order by ID_KEY) rn
      FROM [PBM].[T_CHARGES] A LEFT OUTER JOIN
           [OGEN].[NDC_M_FORMULARY] B
            ON A.[NDC] = B.[NDC] 
     Where [STAT] not in (3, 4) AND [TIER] <> 'T1'
    ) a
where rn = 1;
```

There is no indication where `stat` and `tier` come from.  My guess is that one or more of them come from the `ndc_m_formulary` table.  If I had to choose one, I would guess `tier`.  In any case, whatever comes from the "b" table should be in the `on` clause, not the `where` clause.  This comparison is undoing the `left outer join` and turning it into a regular `inner join`:

```
select *
from (SELECT ID_KEY, [BATCH] AS column1, [IMPORTDATE], [DATEBILLED], [RX], [DATEDISPENSED],
               [DAYSUPPLY], [PAYTYPE], [NPI], [PHYSICIAN], [COST], [QUANTITY], [MEDICATION],
               A.[NDC], [PATIENTNAME], [ROUTEOFADMIN], [INVOICECAT], [COPAY], [BRAND], [TIER],
               [SKILLLEVEL], [STAT] STATUS, [LASTTASKDATE], SEQNO, B.[SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS],
              row_number() over(partition by ID_KEY order by ID_KEY) rn
      FROM [PBM].[T_CHARGES] A LEFT OUTER JOIN
           [OGEN].[NDC_M_FORMULARY] B
           ON A.[NDC] = B.[NDC]  AND [TIER] <> 'T1'
     Where [STAT] not in (3, 4)
    ) a
where rn = 1;
```

Good formatting and the use of table aliases for *all* column references will actually help you write SQL code that you will get to work correctly faster.

Comment: tier and stat are from the first table. all we want from the second tbl is the substr_instructions.

Comment: @user3273561 . . . If that is indeed the case, then you should be getting one row by `ID_KEY`, just as your query is specifying.